# Understanding the decay of Na-22

Tags: radiation, radioactivity, isotopes

When looking at data for Na-22 decay (e.g. here: https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat3/DecayRadiationServlet?nuc=22Na&unc=NDS ) it shows that for every 100 decays, there should be:

99.94 gammas with 1274keV,

179.91 gammas with 511 keV,

however when looking at spectra, it seems that the 511 keV peak is around 5-10 times higher than the one at 1274keV. Even accounting for the higher width of the 1274keV peak does not give the expected result (i.e. the integral over the 511keV peak is 1.8 times that of the 1274keV peak)

Examples for spectra:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12648-021-02210-1 (Fig. 4)

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271140407_Characterization_studies_of_Silicon_Photomultipliers_and_crystals_matrices_for_a_novel_time_of_flight_PET_detector (Fig. 18)

Can anyone help me with this? Are my assumptions made above correct?

Comment: Detector efficiency, perhaps?  Neither of the sources above discuss this directly but IIRC scintillators are typically less responsive at higher energies.

Comment: Isn't 1.8 times pretty exactly what you'd expect if its a plot of photon counts, instead of energy deposited in the detector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparent discrepancy is because you are not correcting for the higher efficiencies of the detectors for detecting lower energy gammas.

Your first spectrum ("Fig. 4") is taken with a standard 3x3" NaI detector which is about 3 times more efficient at detecting 511 keV gammas than 1274 KeV gammas. You can take the efficiencies from Table 2 of ["Optimization of 3×3 inch NaI(Tl) detector related to energy, distance and bias voltage"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jrras.2023.100613), and then correct for their FWHM (50 vs 70 KeV from Fig. 6 in the spectrum paper). The ratio of heights (~5) of the 511 and 1274 KeV peaks in your first spectrum is then pretty much exactly what you'd expect if their production ratio is 1.8.

Your second spectrum ("Fig. 18") uses a LYSO(Ce) detector whose precise efficiency I cannot immediately find, but the efficiency of any detector will be lower for 1274 KeV gammas than 511 KeV gammas because the absorption length for all materials is lower. See, for example, the elemental [photon absorption lengths](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/tab3.html) from NIST for the components of LYSO scintillator, e.g. [Lutetium](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z71.html) and [Ytterbium](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z70.html).

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing several different gamma mechanisms.

Going to the ENSDF database for Na-22 to Ne-22 ones sees the level diagram as:

[image]

where you can see that 89.90% of the decays are positron emission, and 10.04% are electron capture. Further, 99.943% of all decays go to the intermediate 2+ nuclear level, which then provides the 1274.53 keV gamma.

Wholly separate is what the positron from 89.90% of the decays does. Those positrons annihilate with electrons to make two 511 keV gammas. These 511 keV gammas have nothing to do with the Ne-22 daughter nucleus.

So, out of 100 total decays one should get 99.943 of the 1274.53 keV gammas (a small minority of decays go to the ground state). Then, from the 89.90 positrons emitted one should get $2 \times 89.90 = 179.8$ 511 keV gammas.